Why is my Windows laptop not querying local DNS server?
I have a local PowerDNS server. It works fine on my Windows laptop under Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). dig @main probitas returns the expected address. ping probitas and lynx http://probitas also work on WSL.
Windows DNS settings are configured to use the localhost server, but in Windows Firefox "http://probitas" fails and "ping probitas" on Windows terminal fails.
The Windows network adapter first DNS server  192.168.0.100 (local PowerDNS server) and second is 192.168.0.1 (router). I can access the Internet, but Windows does not seem to use the DNS settings I entered. What's wrong?

You may need more than "fails" to pursue this. Given that Windows queries DNS servers in parallel and selects the first response, the first thing to do is localize the configuration so that only one DNS server is configured. Then elaborate on the "fails", is it a timeout, nxdomain, etc. You also need to use tools external to the application, such as nslookup, and test multiple different fully qualified names, not single label unqualified names.

Many modern web browsers can be configured to NOT use the system DNS settings and can be configured to use application specific DNS servers (for privacy, security and/or reliability).
Some browsers will do this by default, others may ask (once) and/or that may be an more hidden option in the advanced settings.
Check your Firefox DNS-over-HTTPS / "DNS privacy protection"  settings.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/dns-over-https-doh-faqs

In addition: DNS servers expect requests with fully qualified hostnames i.e. hostname.example.com. The ability to use  short hostnames like hostname works only when/because your OS (and/or system resolver) is configured to append a "search domain" to short hostnames when it attempts to use DNS to resolve them. So when there is no hostname entry in a hosts file, the system resolver appends example.com. and then attempts to resolve hostname.example.com. via DNS.
